# Suspend docker-compose container shutdown until result of a condition is true?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, shutdown, task-queue, graceful-shutdown

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that defines a number of services. One is a `redis` instance, and another is a `queue-worker`.

The `queue-worker` fetches jobs from `redis` and performs the necessary work.

Currently, I have the `queue-worker`'s `stop_grace_period` set to `5m`, within my `docker-compose.yml`. The idea here is that when I run `docker-compose down`, the `queue-worker` will have 5 minutes to deal with any remaining jobs in the queue, before shutting down.

I would like to improve the situation, if possible, by performing a check when `docker-compose down` is called. If the result of the check is true, e.g. `curl http://project/total-jobs-in-queue == 0` then go ahead and stop the `queue-worker` container immediately. If the result is false, i.e. there are still jobs in the work queue, delay container shutdown until the result of the check is true.

I *could* write a bash script to perform this check, and shut the containers individually, from within the script, however if it was possible to configure this in such a way that the standard `docker-compose up/down` commands could continue to be used, that would be much more preferable.

Is this possible?

Comment: I do not understand. `stop the container immediately` Just exit the process that is running.

Comment: I don't want the ```queue-worker``` container to stop if there is still work in the queue.

Comment: Is that `queue-worker` a program _you_ have written and have control over?

Comment: Yes. It's a python script running in a linux shell / python environment.

Comment: So handle the SIGTERM signal in your python script and terminate your script when that condition is satisfied. `stop_grace_period` is about delay between SIGTERM and SIGKILL. You script receives SIGTERM, so terminate it gracefully as fast as posisble.

Comment: Not possible on docker/docker-compose configuration level. You have to do a script for that, you can make it a while loop with sleep script or a cron job, depends on other factors. But anyway, you will need a custom way